# declaring a C# Generic Type method

Tags: c#, generics

I have a class:

```
internal class Paginated<T> where T : class
{
    public List<T> data { get; set; }

    public int total { get; set; }
    public int page { get; set; }
    public int per_page { get; set; }
    public Paging paging { get; set; }
}
```

and in another class, I have method:

```
public T RequestAllPaginated<T>() where T : Paginated<AnyType> //AnyType???
{
    var item = Request<T>();

    //Get all data from paging property
    if(item != null)
    {
        var i = item as Paginated<AnyType>; //AnyType???
        var data = i.data;

    }

    return item;
}
```

T is always a `Paginated<AnyType>` type. The question is how can I determine in `RequestAllPaginated` method declaration and cast it later on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this solution

```
public T RequestAllPaginated<T, TK>() where T : Paginated<TK> where TK : class
{
    var item = Request<T>();

    //Get all data from paging property
    if(item != null)
    {
        var i = item as Paginated<TK>;
        var data = i.data;

    }

    return item;
}
```

Alternative solution:

```
public Paginated<T> RequestAllPaginated<T>() where T : class
{
    var item = Request<Paginated<T>>();

    //Get all data from paging property
    if(item != null)
    {
        var i = item as Paginated<T>;
        var data = i.data;

    }

    return item;
}
```

Comment: TK is part of T, which makes it redundant to declare TK and I cann't change RequestAllPaginated<Paginated<Album>> to  RequestAllPaginated<Paginated<Album>, Album>.